# Can I use Weblogic 10.3 to build applications that run on WebLogic server 9.2?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, backwards-compatibility

I have WebLogic 10.3 installed (Server, Workshop and Portal).
However, some of the legacy service applications are deployed on WebLogic 9.2.
I have noticed that after using Ant to build the service library, I get an EBJ stub named **ABCD_be9p7l_EOImpl_1030_WLStub.class**.
Building it from WebLogic 9.2 gives **ABCD_be9p7l_EOImpl_922_WLStub.class**.
My question is, if I deploy the 10.3 one in the 9.2 server, will there be any compatibility issues that will stop the services from running?
If there is, is there any way that I can use WebLogic 10.3 to build applications that run on 9.2?

Answer (score 0):

Read ["Compatibility Statement for Oracle® WebLogic Server 10g Release 3 (10.3)"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/compatibility/compatibility.html) document:

> Oracle attempts to support binary and source-level compatibility between the current version of WebLogic Server and all versions as far back as 8.1 in the areas of persistent data, generated classes, and API compatibility. In some cases, it is impossible to avoid incompatibilities.

and ["Upgrading WebLogic Application Environments"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/upgrade/index.html) article:

> Application environments that run with WebLogic Server 10.3 can interact with application environments built on WebLogic Server 7.0, 8.1, 9.x, or 10.0.
>
> Most existing WebLogic Server applications can be run without modification in the new WebLogic Server 10.3 application environment. You should review the compatibility information described in WebLogic Server 10.3 Compatibility with Previous Releases to determine whether any feature changes affect the applications in your environment. If your application uses APIs that have been deprecated or removed, then you may encounter warnings or exceptions at run time.